# Protractor: How to bypass login(Okta) for e2e testing?

Tags: angular, protractor, okta

I currently have had a login component added to my app, and in order to use the features of my app, I must be logged in. Now this is a problem because the implementation of the login is not my code, rather an authentication service (okta). So I cannot just manually enter my log in credentials and sign in with a beforeEach() test (as far as I know). If that is possible and I am able to open to it, I am unsure how I would access the elements. Is there a way I can store a user profile to protractor so that I am already signed into my app with protractor so that I do not need to sign in? I am currently using Chrome and angular 4+ if that helps. If this is not possible, please let me know and I will have to manually sign in. Any input is great, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the ts file for e.g given below which can store the user credentials to login. As part of beforeEach() you can navigate to login page and provide appropriate values in textbox.

```
export const testData = {
    Tenant1: {
        email: 'abc@tenant1.com',
        password: 'tenant1-password',
        url: 'tentant1'
    },
    Tenant2: {
        email: 'abc@tenant2.com',
        password: 'tenant2-password',
        url: 'tentant2'
    }
};
```

Also you should close the browser after each test case, in case you plan to use different logins. "restartBrowserBetweenTests: true," attribute can be set in protractor.conf.js

Comment: Thank you, I guess I will just mock a log in with the beforeEach(). My new problem now is that when I log in, I get a 400. So the server is not properly getting the info I am sending. If I cannot figure that out, I will probably post a question here. It could be because rather then clicking a log in button, I just direct protractor to the log in page with browser.get (my log in button does not appear to be visible to protractor).

Comment: Here's a blog post I wrote on how to implement Protractor tests (among others) with Okta. It uses environment variables for username and password. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/05/02/testing-spring-boot-angular-components